# How to access method without create object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to create system like `System()->parameter()->parmKey` or `like`

it's return value `123`

`parmKey` not fixed it's a change or dynamically

I am not sure, how can implement this system in laravel

Answer (score 1):

this is feature in php oop named Chaining methods
example :

```html
<?php
class Message 
{
    public $message;
  
    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->message = "";
    }
  
    public function newLine($line)
    {
        $this->message .= $line;
      
        return $this;
    }
  
    public function getMessage()
    {         
        return $this->message;
    }
}


$message = new Message();

echo $message->newLine('Hello')->newLine('My name is yazan')->getMessage();
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Can you perhaps summarise the points of the related link instead to make it easier for users to get an answer - or mark this question as a duplicate

Comment: I hope this will useful